# Transaction tracking

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I create a transaction tracking for my app? 
I would like to check every action my users.

Payment

```
record transaction of the following and with the fields inputed:
creating payment
editing payment
deleting payment
```

Other Activities

```
Record add, edit, view and delete of other parts of the app including the fields input
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ActiveSupport::Notifications` for this

http://asciicasts.com/episodes/249-notifications-in-rails-3